# Pandas iloc vs direct slicing?

Tags: python, pandas

I've read a lot of discussion about iloc vs loc and I understand the difference but what I don't understand is what's the difference between:

```
indexed_data['var'][0:10]
```

vs

```
indexed_data['var'].iloc[0:10]
```

These seem to be the same thing and give the same output.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In last versions of pandas this was work for `ix` function.

But from pandas 0.20+ [ix indexer is deprecated](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated).

So use `get_loc` for position of `var` column and select with `iloc` only:

```
indexed_data.iloc[0:10, df.columns.get_loc('var')]
```

---

In my opinion difference between:

```
indexed_data['var'][0:10]
```

and:

```
indexed_data['var'].iloc[0:10]
```

is mainly in `][`. I think the best is avoid it because possible `chaining indexing`.

---

[Modern pandas by Tom Augspurger (pandas dev) get advice](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro.html):

> The rough rule is any time you see back-to-back square brackets, **][**, you're in asking for trouble. Replace that with a `.loc[..., ...]` and you'll be set.

So the best is use native pandas function like `loc`, `iloc` here.

Then try compare functions called for each method but after one 40 minutes I stop it (really a lot of function is called).

I check **timings** and are different for each function:

```
indexed_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(2000000,1)), columns=['var'])

In [151]: %timeit indexed_data['var'].iloc[0:100000]
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.1 µs per loop

In [152]: %timeit indexed_data['var'][0:100000]
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.3 µs per loop

In [153]: %timeit indexed_data.iloc[0:100000, indexed_data.columns.get_loc('var')]
10000 loops, best of 3: 155 µs per loop

In [154]: %timeit indexed_data.loc[indexed_data.index[0:100000], 'var']
100 loops, best of 3: 7.36 ms per loop

#numpy approach - output is array 
In [155]: %timeit indexed_data['var'].values[0:100000]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.35 µs per loop
```

Comment: Didn't know `get_loc`, was looking for something like that earlier today :)

Comment: Could you explain why? I'd have thought using the keys was more "pythonic". I just don't get the difference between direct slicing and using iloc.

Comment: I'm not using ix and understand that it's deprecated (there are lots of posts on ix vs iloc vs loc and I've read them).

Comment: I try create some answer, but not easy for me. I need more time :( So sorry.

Comment: great answer. +1 for the *link alone* this has been a frequently asked about "issue" and I think that link will answer *a lot* of questions

Answer (score 6):

As a complement to the other answers, also observe the following note from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html#selection):

> While standard Python / Numpy expressions for selecting and setting are intuitive and come in handy for interactive work, for production code, we recommend the optimized pandas data access methods, `.at`, `.iat`, `.loc` and `.iloc`.

Answer (score 4):

alternative solution:

```
indexed_data.loc[indexed_data.index[0:10], 'var']
```

Please read [Pandas docs about "Different Choices for Indexing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) - it'll help to decide which indexer to use for different cases...