# What is the difference between s[i] and s.iloc[i] in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

The similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983801/pandas-iloc-vs-direct-slicing), but I don't think it has a very perfect answer. If I am slicing a series rather than a data frame, what is the difference between these two?

`s[i]` vs `s.iloc[i]` and `s[i:i+10]` vs `s.iloc[i: i+10]`?

What if the series is a slice of a dataframe in the first place, for example: `s=df["col1"]`, does the two slicing methods have any difference?

Please give concrete example to explain which is better in practice. Right now, the first slicing method is more preferable to me, because it make the code shorter.

Comment: `s[i]` and `s.iloc[i]` are not the same thing, no. Try with a dataframe with, say, an integer index.

Comment: I know you are talking about a Pandas series. Series have an index.

Comment: Helpful feedback: telling people to read a question [carefully] will generally be regarded as startlingly impolite to a native English speaker. It really is best avoided, and may have been the cause of the downvotes here.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the reminder. At the time of writing, I was thinking about people didn't get what I am asking. It turned out to be the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing (using `[..]`) into a series (and a dataframe) acts as sort of a Swiss Army knife; it has to support a variety of use-cases, and these use-cases are not always compatible or efficient. Using `Series[...]` requires Pandas to check the datatype of both the object you passed and the current index type, and translate your request into the correct rows to return.

Using indexing on the `.iloc` object on the other hand, is *unambigiously* meant to only accept integer indices and slices. Nothing else. This can then also be optimised, and should be preferred in production code. From the [*Selecting and Indexing* documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

> The Python and NumPy indexing operators `[]` and attribute operator `.` provide quick and easy access to pandas data structures across a wide range of use cases. This makes interactive work intuitive, as there’s little new to learn if you already know how to deal with Python dictionaries and NumPy arrays. However, since the type of the data to be accessed isn’t known in advance, directly using standard operators has some optimization limits. For production code, we recommended that you take advantage of the optimized pandas data access methods exposed in this chapter.

Moreover, you can't always use `[...]` to index into a series, not when you have an integer index already with values that are not aligned with the row indices:

```
>>> a = pd.Series([41, 82], index=[2, 1])
>>> s.iloc[0]
41
>>> s[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 623, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2557, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 83, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 811, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 817, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Indexing the first row fails with `s[0]`, because there's an integer index. You'd have to use `s[2]` instead to address the specific cell here.

When using *slicing*, Python passes in a `slice()` object to the underlying code handling the `s[...]` and `s.iloc[...]` operations (`__getitem__` methods), so that's easier to detect, and will give you the same outcome on either.

Comment: Thanks, this example is enough for me to stick with .iloc